# How do change the pixels of a canvas on a online website so that other people can see the changes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas, google-chrome-extension

Currently im programming a chrome extension which is a **drawing bot for the website skribbl.io**. I already made one in java, however i figured that there are ways to draw faster and have the drawing show up faster for others when coding the bot in chrome as an extension.

Im stuck on figuring out how i can **edit the canvas of skribbl.io**, which i managed to save in a variable so far, **so that other people can see which pixels ive edited**. I can change the context of the canvas and apply it, but only i can see it. I also tried simulating mouseClicks, which didnt work, but i dont want to go that route as its basically the same as using the java robot
class, which i already implemented in my first bot.

**Im a beginner, and any help would be appreciated.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean editing the canvas client side and allowing other people on other clients to see it, you can't do that.

You will have to use scribbl's own methods of editing the canvas I believe. Which would likely involve the simulated mouse clicks as you have said.

Comment: What about socket io and websockets, how could they be used?

Comment: Wouldnt be any different, sockets just help with managing the processes between your web server and the client it's communicating with. The problem with this is that scribble has their own way of changing their canvas, you cant overwrite that, it simply can't be done without simulating mouse movements. Unless they have an API or something similar which i doubt